# Call a Static Method Using a String of the Class's filename in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, filenames

Let's say I use file.list() to get all the files in the src folder. Pretend one filename is called Problem0001.java. Is it possible to call the method of the Problem0001.java class using only the String "Problem0001.java"?

Deeper explaination:
   I'm working on problems from project Euler. Project Euler are a bunch of problems that require math and programming knowledge. I want each problem to be solved it it's own class. I decided that it would be awesome if I can create a menu where I type in the problem number and the answer shows up on the screen. I started out with a switch statement that would call the class that had the problem solution. I figured eventually I would get sick and tired of adding to the switch statement each time I solved a new problem. I want the computer to find all the solution class files and put the number of the solution in a list (Since I might skip some problems). Whenever I enter the menu screen, the list will be printed out. I type in the number of the solution that I want to see, and this is the part where I'm lost. I somehow need to take that number and call the static method of the class with the same number. So if I type in 3, classfile Problem0003.java will activate, or however the compiler works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have a class name, you will have to load the class at runtime using `ClassLoader` to get hold of `.class`

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.someorg.SomeClass");
```

Once you have that you can invoke static methods using [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName", String.class);
method.invoke(null,"someString");
```

Note: Assuming the method takes a string as an argument is `String.class`

Comment: Please have mercy on me. What is "org.someorg.SomeClass". Does this have to do with stuff on websites? I'm just working locally. Would I replace that with my directory instead?

Comment: It is a standard for naming the packages : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html this will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much. Took me one day to read on how to make it work. Finally. BTW I tried to invoke(null, null), but it seems you need to put in an object in Invoke(object, null); that or I don't know what I'm talking about, but it seems to only work when I do that.

Comment: `method.invoke(..)` ignores the instance of the class that you have passed in as an argument "the object on which the method is to be called" as the method is static it does not require instance of that class to invoke the method on it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, using java [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

take a look at an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/) of how to call a method at runtime.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't taught this in class. I'll read this up and try it out right away!